# Continuous function on a compact metric space with no fixed point

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, and suppose $f:X \to X$ is a continuous map with no fixed point.  Show that there is an $\epsilon > 0$ so that $d(f(x),x) \ge \epsilon \  \forall x \in X$.

I considered a function $g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x) = d(f(x),x)$ so that there is a fixed point only when $g(x)=0$. Is there a way to proceed using this function?

Comment: `$f: X \to X$` for example.

Comment: If $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists x \in X$ such that $d\left( f\left( x \right), x \right) < \epsilon$, then $x$ will be a fixed point of $f$. Hence, the result.

Answer (score 2):

The function $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined $g(x) = d(f(x),x)$ is continuous because it is a composition of continuous functions. For every $\epsilon > 0$ let $I_{\varepsilon} = \{r\in \mathbb{R} \mid r > \varepsilon\}$, which is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $g^{-1}(I_{\varepsilon})$ is open in $X$, and the family of sets $\{g^{-1}(I_{\varepsilon}) \mid \varepsilon > 0 \}$ covers $X$ because $X$ has no fixed point. Since $X$ is compact, any open cover of it will have a finite subcover: $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}  g^{-1}(I_{\varepsilon_i})$. Let $\varepsilon_{min} = \min\{\varepsilon_i,\dots,\varepsilon_n\}$. Then for every $x\in X$ we have $x \in g^{-1}(I_{\varepsilon_i})$ for some $i$, hence $d(f(x),x) = g(x) \in I_{\varepsilon_i}$, so $d(f(x),x) > \varepsilon_i \geq \varepsilon_{min}$, and we are done.

Comment: The continuous image of a compact space is compact. So if $X$ is not empty then $g(X)$ is a compact ( and hence closed )  non-empty subset of $[0,\infty)$ and therefore $g(X)$ has a minimum  member

Answer (score 1):

For metric spaces, compactness and sequential compactness are the same.  Assume that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists x \in X$ such that $d(f(x),x)< \epsilon$.  Then we get a sequence $x_i$ of points such that $d(f(x_i),x_i)$ converges to 0.  Sequential compactness gives us the desired limit point $x^*$ that is a fixed point.  This is a contradiction.